# Selenium chromedriver opens a blank page instead of url on linux

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open a url in chromedriver(using RemoteWebDriver) on linux.

I took a screenshot after driver.get(url) is called. It displays a blank page.

[east-northamptonshire_screenshot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3hnC.png)

I tried this(open a url using ChromeDriver) on my local machine(Windows). It is working fine.

This is the url I am trying to open. "https://publicaccess.east-northamptonshire.gov.uk/online-applications/search.do?action=weeklyList"

Main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

    WebDriver driver = null;
    ChromeDriverService service = null;

    boolean isWindows = OS.indexOf("win") >= 0;
    logger.info("operating System : " + OS);
    if (!isWindows) {
        service = new ServerChromeDriver().loadService();
    }
    driver = new ServerChromeDriver().getPIDriver(service, isWindows);

    String url = "https://publicaccess.east-northamptonshire.gov.uk/online-applications/search.do?action=weeklyList";
    driver.get(url);

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    ScreenShot.takeScreenShot(driver);

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
    service.stop();
}
```

ServerChromeDriver Class:

```
  public ChromeDriverService loadService() throws Exception {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.loadProperties();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream("config//log4j.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);

    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File(configuration.getChromeDriverPath()))
            .usingAnyFreePort().withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY", configuration.getDisplay())).build();
    service.start();

    return service;
}

  public WebDriver getPIDriver(ChromeDriverService service, boolean isWindows) {

    WebDriver driver;

    if (isWindows) {
        driver = new LocalChromeDriver().getDriver();
    } else {
        driver = new ServerChromeDriver().getDriver(service.getUrl());
    }

    String hostName = new ServerChromeDriver().getHostName(driver);
    logger.info("Running the application on host: " + hostName);

    return driver;
}

public WebDriver getDriver(URL serviceUrl) {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.loadProperties();
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    // chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1800,1800");
    // chromeOptions.addExtensions(new File(configuration.getAdBlockPath()));


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", configuration.getChromeDriverPath());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", configuration.getChromeDriverLogFilePath());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", configuration.getChromeVerboseLogging());

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    try {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(serviceUrl, capabilities);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error creating a new chrome instance");
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return driver;
}
```

Application is working fone for this url: https://eplanning.birmingham.gov.uk/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/GeneralSearch.aspx

[birmingham_screenshot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIhVq.png)

I am using

```
Headless Chrome : 67.0.3396.62
chromedriver    : 2.40.565383
```

This is what I found from the chromedriver.log file

```
[0617/144457.403693:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(601)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: crt.comodoca.com
[0617/144457.403801:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(980)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for publicaccess.east-northamptonshire.gov.uk failed err=-8179
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because Chrome version in your Linux machine is not supported.

Comment: I am able to open other url's. Only few url's are causing this issue. This is one of those url's

Answer (score 1):

For people using newer versions of Selenium who are dealing with this issue, I was able to do the following (similar to Abhilash's answer which is using an older version of Selenium) to resolve the blank-page issue for uncertified domains with Chrome:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();    
...
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
...
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

(In my case, webdriver worked fine on my local machine but not on the Linux box hosting CI tools)

Answer (score 0):

After researching about certificate errors, I have added additional capabilities to chrome driver to ignore certificate related errors. Below is my solution.

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
        capabilities.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true); // Added this additionally
        capabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true); // Added this additionally
        capabilities.setCapability("ignore-certificate-errors", true); // Added this additionally
```